# subsetting an element of a list of dataframes

Tags: r

i have f which is a list of 3 data-frames. The summary of f is as follows

```
> summary(f)
     Length Class      Mode
[1,] 4      data.frame list
[2,] 4      data.frame list
[3,] 4      data.frame list
```

further

```
> str(f)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   2557 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Date   : Factor w/ 2557 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ sulfate: num [1:2557] NA NA 3.82 NA NA NA NA NA 3.1 NA ...
  ..$ nitrate: num [1:2557] NA NA 0.494 NA NA NA NA NA 0.452 NA ...
  ..$ ID     : int [1:2557] 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   1826 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Date   : Factor w/ 1826 levels "2006-01-01","2006-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ sulfate: num [1:1826] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ nitrate: num [1:1826] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ ID     : int [1:1826] 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   2191 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Date   : Factor w/ 2191 levels "2001-01-01","2001-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ sulfate: num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ nitrate: num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ ID     : int [1:2191] 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 ...
```

Now f[1] is the first data-frame of the list. I want to subset it such that i will get only the column of sulfur or nitrate. Therefore i pass the code such that

```
pol<-"nitrate"
f[1][[pol]]  which failed. i tried many other ways like,f[1][,pol],f[1][,nitrate] etc.
```

None of them works. Pls help me here. i am completely lost.

Comment: For list, use f[[1]]

Comment: You should ask for help on the coursera-forums.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `[[` to extract an element from a `list`.  If we need the first element, it would be `f[[1]]` and it is a `data.frame`, so subsetting by column names will get the column of that `data.frame` and return a `data.frame`.

```
f[[1]]['sulfate']
```

If we need to return a `vector`,

```
f[[1]][['sulfate']]
```

or

```
f[[1]][, 'sulfate']
```

can be used.

The `f[1]` is still a `list`.  We can look at the `str(f[1])` and `str(f[[1]])` to understand the structure.